# Can I use an object in function's parameter in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need to use:

```
var obj=document.getElementsByClassName[n];
setInterval("somefunc("+obj+");",10);
```

When I'm trying to run this code, I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier". I know about this problem with `setTimeout("alert("+str+");)`, when I should use `.toString()`, but what if I need to pass an object in function?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can but like this:

```
setInterval(function(){
   somefunc(obj);
},10);
```

So here is how your code should be:

```
var obj = document.getElementsByClassName(n);
setInterval(function(){
   somefunc(obj);
},10);
```

---

You had these problems with your previous code:

- You were calling your function ***immediately*** by passing param eg `someFun(obj)`
- You were using `eval()` function behind the scenes by wrapping your code in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

```
setInterval(function () { somefunc(obj) }, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use it like

```
var obj=document.getElementsByClassName[n];
setInterval(function() {return somefunc(obj)},10);
```